# Angular get to JSON file displaying as empty

Tags: json, angularjs, http, get, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular and trying to integrate it within my application. I am attempting to use a simple `$http.get` to a .JSON file, which seems to be found, but when trying to pass the data to the front end, or even alert it, is it alerting as []

Here my get:

```
$scope.countries = [];
    $http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json', function(data){
            $scope.countries = data;
        }, function(error) {
            //handle error here
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.countries));
```

Here's my .JSON file:

```
{
  "firstName"   : "Joe",
  "surName" : "Bloggs",
  "countries" : [
      { "name": "France", "population": "63.1" },
      { "name": "Span", "population": "52.3" },
      { "name": "United Kingdom", "population": "61.8" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The $http.get is asynchronous and hasn't completed yet. If you put a $watch on 'countries', the callback will run when $scope.countries is updated. You could also use {{countries}} in one of your views and you'll see the data in the view when it returns.

Comment: @EthanJewett - sorry, where should $watch go?

Comment: Anywhere in your controller. The other answers are correct as well. I would suggest logging in your success function before you assign data to $scope.countries, as it sounds from your responses to other answers like you're never getting to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.countries = [];
$http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json', function(data){
        $scope.countries = data;
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.countries));
    }, function(error) {
        //handle error here
});
```

Alert should go in the callback.

Comment: Tried the above, even added console.log("console = " + JSON.stringify($scope.countries)); but the alert or console message never displays.. But in Firebug, i can see a successful GET to the JSON file and the data inside.

Comment: Yup, added function(error) {
        alert("error");
    }); and no alert appeard.

Comment: Maybe like this :
`$http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json')
.success(function(data) {
alert(data);
}.error(function() {
console.error("$http.get() error");
}`

Comment: @Myzuno - i think a ; or ) or } is missing.

Comment: Tried: $http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json').success(function(data) { 
     alert(data); 
    }); and an alert appears with [object Object]

Comment: Then it works. There was probably some problem with stringify. By the way shouldn't it be $scope.countries = data.countries?

Comment: @ppa Yes, it's work
So try to `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`
or just `console.log(data)`, you will see your data in console.

Comment: @Myzuno - tried alert(JSON.stringify(data)); console.log(data); console.log(data.firstName); nothing is alert'ed or shown in the console.

Comment: Into success function ? huum strange :/
I didn't see before, but if data is on json format, you must use JSON.parse(data), not stringify. I don't know if it will solve your problem, but maybe `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` will work ?

Comment: @ppa the code in the answer is not correct. Should be `$http.get(...).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback)` or `$http.get(...).then(successCallback, errorCallback)` see docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
$http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.countries));
  }).error(function(error) {
    alert('error');
  });
```

also this equivalent would work

```
$http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json').then(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.countries));
  }, function(error) {
    alert('error');
  });
```

Edit --

1. Instead of $http.get('/someUrl', sucessCallback, errorCallback) it should be either

   ```
   $http.get('/someUrl').success(successCallback).error(errorCallback)
   ```

   or

   ```
   $http.get('/someUrl').then(successCallback, errorCallback)
   ```

   [see docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#get)
2. Because $http.get is asynchronous alert should be moved in the successCallback function, to ensure that `$scope.countries=data` is executed before calling alert.

Comment: im not sure how this helps?

Comment: I was testing the code in a plunker first and forgot to change the url of the json file back to yours when I posted. I just re-edited accordingly.

Comment: OK you got it working, just edited to clarify my answer anyway. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

$http.get is an async function. when you try `alert(JSON.stringify($scope.countries));` $scope.countries is equals to []. You must wait for server response before using data.

Try to do your alert into success function

```
$scope.countries = [];
$http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json', function(data){
        $scope.countries = data;
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.countries));
    }, function(error) {
        //handle error here
});
```

Comment: @Mysuno - Tried the above, even added console.log("console = " + JSON.stringify($scope.countries)); but the alert or console message never displays.. But in Firebug, i can see a successful GET to the JSON file and the data inside.