# Accessing elements in JSON file

Tags: json, angularjs, http, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am attempting to use a simple $http.get to a .JSON file, which seems to be found, but when trying to pass the data to the front end, i am seeing an error in my console:

```
Error: data.unitedkindgom: is undefined
```

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller("CityController", function($scope, $http, cityService) {

$scope.UKCities = [];

cityService.getCityData(function(data) {

    $scope.UKCities = data.unitedkindgom.CityInfo;

    console.log(data.unitedkindgom.CityInfo);        

});
```

My JSON:

```
unitedkindgom: {
"NoCities": 66,
"Balance": 2103,
"Population":  63705000,
"CityInfo": [
    {
        "CityName": "London",
        "CityPopulation": "7825200",
        "Facts": {
            "SubFact1": "xzy",
            "SubFact2": "xzy",
            "SubFact3": "xzy",
            "SubFact4": "xzy",
            "SubFact5": "xzy"
        },
    },
    {
        "CityName": "Manchester",
        "CityPopulation": "2584241",
        "Facts": {
            "SubFact1": "abc",
            "SubFact2": "abc",
            "SubFact3": "abc",
            "SubFact4": "abc"
        },
    }

],
"SubmitInfo": null,
"FormAction": null,
"FormController": null,
}
```

Thanks

---

UPDATE

**cityService.getCityData**

```
app.factory('cityService', function($http) {
    return {
        getCityData: function(done) {
            $http.get('/data/city.json')
            .success(function(data) { done(data);})
            .error(function(error) {
                alert('An error has occured');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

---

UPDATE

If i remove `$scope.UKCities = data.unitedkindgom.CityInfo;` and replace `console.log(data.unitedkindgom.CityInfo);` with `console.log(data);` I can see all my data in the console window.

If replace `console.log(data.unitedkindgom.CityInfo);` with `console.log(data.unitedkindgom);` I see `Undefined` in the console window.

Comment: `$http` works asynchronously, you log the variable before `$http` returns the results, so it logs as `undefined`. This is an extremely common problem and can be solved by using promises.

Comment: Show us code of `cityService.getCityData`

Comment: @Satpal - cityService.getCityData

Comment: @OamPsy That's because `getCityData` does not return anything. Try `return $http.get(...)` and handle the callback inside the controller.

Comment: @CodeHater - any more information would be appreciated. I followed the exact same get to a different .JSON in a different project and it worked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135773/angular-get-to-json-file-displaying-as-empty

Comment: @OamPsy in that question, the `$http` code is not in a factory but in a controller most likely, and it can update the $scope itself when it's done with the async operation

Comment: If i remove $scope.UKCities = data.unitedkindgom.CityInfo; and replace console.log(data.unitedkindgom.CityInfo);  with console.log(data);  I can see all my data in the console window.

Comment: Oh that is quite important information :-P It turns out your JSON is invalid

Comment: @TimCastelijns - i had a feeling you may say that. is it because it starts with: unitedkindgom:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), I found out that your JSON is invalid, so it can't be parsed

Below is a valid JSON of your data

```
{
    "unitedkindgom": {
        "NoCities": 66,
        "Balance": 2103,
        "Population": 63705000,
        "CityInfo": [
            {
                "CityName": "London",
                "CityPopulation": "7825200",
                "Facts": {
                    "SubFact1": "xzy",
                    "SubFact2": "xzy",
                    "SubFact3": "xzy",
                    "SubFact4": "xzy",
                    "SubFact5": "xzy"
                }
            },
            {
                "CityName": "Manchester",
                "CityPopulation": "2584241",
                "Facts": {
                    "SubFact1": "abc",
                    "SubFact2": "abc",
                    "SubFact3": "abc",
                    "SubFact4": "abc"
                }
            }
        ],
        "SubmitInfo": null,
        "FormAction": null,
        "FormController": null
    }
}
```

Note that its entirely wrapped in `{ }`, `unitedkindgom` is wrapped in `" "` and here and there some excess `,` are removed.